# Sidebar with dropdown menu from database

Tags: php, html, laravel-5

I'm trying to use a database to add menu items on a sidebar on my site. My database is structured as follows:

```
ID / Product_Name/ Product_Type
1 / product1 / type1
2 / product2 / type1
3 / product3 / type2
4 / product4 / type2
```

I need a sidebar which has each type listed as a menu item, with the products belonging to that type as the submenu items:

```
  Type1
    product1 
    product2 
  Type2
    product3
    product4
```

With my current code however I achieve each menu item but my submenu shows every product in the entire database instead of just the products belonging to that type.

My controller:

```
public function index()
{

    //get all products
    $products = Product::all();  

    //get each type
    $types = Product::distinct()->get(['Type']);

    return view('pages.getstarted')->with('products', $products)                                       
                                   ->with('types', $types);
}
```

My view:

```
<ul class="list-sidebar">                                
  @foreach($types as $type)
    <li class="header">
      <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#1">{{$type->Type}}<span class="fa fa-chevron-left pull-right"></span></a>
      <ul class="sub-menu collapse" id="1">
        @foreach($products as $product)
          <li><a href="1">{{$product->Product_Name}}</a></li>
        @endforeach
      </ul>
    </li>   
  @endforeach 
</ul>
```

I am very new to Laravel so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your controller and your view a bit with the `groupBy` method from the `Collection` instance:

[Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-groupby)

**Controller**

```
public function index()
{
    //get all products
    $products = Product::all();  

    return view('pages.getstarted')->with('products', $products);
}
```

**View**

```
<ul class="list-sidebar">
    @foreach($products->groupBy('Product_Type') as $type => $subCollection)
    <li class="header">
        <a data-target="#1" data-toggle="collapse" href="#">
            {{$type}}
            <span class="fa fa-chevron-left pull-right"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="sub-menu collapse" id="1">
            @foreach($subCollection as $product)
            <li>
                <a href="1">{{$product->Product_Name}}</a>
            </li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

Starting from `$types` do the following:

```
    $menu = [];
    foreach ($types as $type){
      $products = Product::where('Product_Type', $type->Product_Type)->get();
       foreach ($products as $product){
          $menu[$type->Product_Type][] = $product->Product_Name;
       }
    }
return view('pages.getstarted',['menu' => $menu]);
```

Then in the view:

```
<ul>
@foreach($menu as $type)
 <li>{{$type}}<ul>
  @foreach($type as $item)
   <li>{{$item}}</li>
  @endforeach
  </ul></li>
@endforeach
</ul>
```